# Javascript - Group by data from object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, group-by

I have the object arrays like below:

```
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};
```

And what I want is to group by `id, name` and list out `rating` belonging its like below

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Spider-man",
    rating: {top: 1, middle: 4.5, bottom: 5}
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Iron man",
    rating: {top: 3, middle: 3.5, bottom: 2}
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Hulk",
    rating: {top: 5, middle: 1.5, bottom: 4}
  }
];
```

I've tried this approach but seems it can achieve in more ways such as `.reduce`, `for...of` with more elegant, right?

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};

var result = obj.top.map(x => ({
  id: x.id,
  name: x.name,
  rating: {
    top: obj.top.find(t => t.id === x.id).rating,
    middle: obj.middle.find(t => t.id === x.id).rating,
    bottom: obj.bottom.find(t => t.id === x.id).rating,
  }
}));
                          
console.log(result);
```

Any other ways to achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to map one of the subarrays to find each character's rating, so I think your current approach is pretty reasonable. You can make it a bit less repetitive by making an array of the properties (`top`, `middle`, `bot`) beforehand, then iterating over them instead of listing each different one:

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};

const props = ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'];
var result = obj.top.map(x => ({
  id: x.id,
  name: x.name,
  rating: Object.fromEntries(
    props.map(prop =>
      [prop, obj[prop].find(t => t.id === x.id).rating]
    )
  )
}));      
console.log(result);
```

Another approach that's less computationally complex:

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};
const byName = {};
for (const [prop, arr] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  for (const item of arr) {
    byName[item.name] ??= { ...item, rating: {} };
    byName[item.name].rating[prop] = item.rating;
  }
}
 
console.log(Object.values(byName));
```

Comment: Yeah, Very like with your approach `You can make it a bit less repetitive`, +1

Comment: The second solution looks [the same to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65930614/12582716), but your code is more elegant and concise, sir. Thanks for the useful.

Comment: Could you pls give me the docs related to this syntax `??=` ? What's it? The same as `??` in [`.NET C#`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)? It's called `null-coalescing-operator`

Comment: @Phong https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment
Shortcut for `if (!byName[item.name]) byName[item.name] =  { ...item, rating: {} }`

Comment: One more question: the second solution would be better than the first by using a `dictionary` with time complexity when searching is `O(1)` . But as you can see, the output just contains 3 items. So the trade-off is here `space` & `time` complexity, right?

Comment: @Phong First code is worse in terms of both time and space complexity, since it has to `.find` and also has to construct bunches of intermediate arrays. But whether complexity is actually an issue to worry about depends on the sorts of inputs you're *really* dealing with. if it's only 3 items, it doesn't matter, you can pick whatever "feels" nicer

Answer (score 1):

Using `Dictionary` along with [`Logical nullish assignment (??=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

The main idea includes 2 steps:

1. Loop all `[key, values]` of the object.
2. Inner each the `values` of the object, we loop to determine which the `user's rating` along with `key` belongs by `user.id`.

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};

// Refactor code: using Dictionary along with `Logical nullish assignment (??=)` .
var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  values.forEach(v => {
    acc[v.id] ??= {...v, rating: {}};
    acc[v.id].rating[key] = v.rating;
  });
  
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(result));

/* Old versions: using Array approach

 var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, values]) => {
  values.forEach(v => {
    var x = acc.find(r => r.id === v.id);
    if(x !== undefined){
      x.rating[key] = v.rating;
    }else{
        x = { id: v.id, name: v.name, rating: {[key]: v.rating} };
        acc.push(x);
      }
  });
  
  return acc;
}, []);
*/
```

**More detailed explanation:**

- With the `dictionary` approach instead of `array`, you can achieve it with the highest performance both `time` and `space` complexity (as [@CertainPerformance's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930558/group-by-data-from-object-arrays#comment116570824_65930596)).
- From [`MDN Web docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) said that:

> The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator `only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a one-liner way

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 },
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 },
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 },
  ],
};

const res = Array.from(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .flatMap(([rater, ratee]) =>
      ratee.map(({ id, name, rating }) => ({
        id,
        name,
        [rater]: rating,
      }))
    )
    .reduce(
      (acc, { id, ...restInfo }) =>
        acc.set(id, { ...(acc.get(id) || {}), ...restInfo }),
      new Map()
    )
).map(([id, { name, ...rating }]) => ({ id, name, rating }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yeah, another nice approach by using `.flatMap` and `reduce`. Just a little bit about complexity concerns. Anyway, thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};


const tempArr1 = Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
  obj[key].forEach((item) => {
    arr = [...arr, { ...item, rating: { [key]: item.rating } }];
  });
  return arr;
}, []);

const result = tempArr1.reduce((arr, el) => {
  let tempObj = { ...el };
  const index = arr.findIndex((tempItem) => tempItem.id === tempObj.id);
  if (~index) {
    arr[index] = {
      ...tempObj,
      rating: {
        ...arr[index].rating,
        ...tempObj.rating
      }
    };
  } else {
    arr = [...arr, tempObj];
  }
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  top: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 5 }
  ],
  middle: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 4.5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 3.5 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 1.5 }
  ],
  bottom: [
    { id: 1, name: "Spider-man", rating: 5 },
    { id: 2, name: "Iron man", rating: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Hulk", rating: 4 }
  ]
};

var result = [];
for(let [key, values] of Object.entries(obj))
  for(let item of values){
    let x = result.find(r => r.id === item.id);
    if(x !== undefined){
      x.rating[key] = item.rating;
    }else{
        x = { id: item.id, name: item.name, rating: {[key]: item.rating} };
        result.push(x);
      }
  }
console.log(result);
```